# How can I get in_array() to work with get_option()?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have two custom fields in my admin settings that allow me to enter two sets of valid zip codes ('woocommerce_local_delivery_zone_a' and 'woocommerce_local_delivery_zone_b').

I cannot figure out why this code isn't working:

```
    $codes_a = get_option( 'woocommerce_local_delivery_zone_a' );
$codes_b = get_option( 'woocommerce_local_delivery_zone_b' );

if ( in_array( "55410", array( $codes_a ) )) {
echo "Codes A";
} 

if ( in_array( "55410", array( $codes_b ) )) {
        echo "Codes B";
}
```

If I echo `$codes_a` or `$codes_b` (outside of the "if" statement), the string of zip codes returns on the page. If I take that string and enter it directly where the variable is in `if (in_array( "55410", array( NUMBERS HERE )))` the text I am trying to echo (`Codes A` or `Codes B`) works.

I also tried placing array( get_option( 'field_name')) directly in the if statement, and that didn't do anything either. Does in_array not work with getting admin custom fields?

Comment: what do you get when you do `var_dump($codes_a);` ?

Comment: I'm assuming the array is serialized. Maybe you can `unserialize()` it and set it to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$codes_a` is a string like this: `08847,032434,35545` then you need to use `explode()` to turn it into an array. I suspect what you really want is this:

```
if ( in_array( "55410", explode( ',', $codes_a ) ) {
    echo "Codes A";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. It seemed counterintuitive to use explode() since it worked when I plugged the numbers directly in, like `if ( in_array( "55410", array( 08847,03243,35545,55410) ))`

Comment: Yes that would work, but since your variable is a string, it would be like doing `array('008847,03243,35545,55410')`. Notice the quotes. You were actually creating an array with just one element that way.